# Unit test false positives because of future callout triggers

Tags: trigger, unit-test, future

**Background**

I have the following Apex class method which is called as a result of a trigger on a custom object, `MySet`:

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void exportMySet(string setId) {
    // do API call to update our database with details of the set
}
```

The trigger on `MySet` that calls this method will activate on `after insert` and also `after update`:

```
trigger setCreatedUpdated on MySet__c (after insert, after update) {
    for (MySet__c currentSet: Trigger.New) {
        SetExport.exportMySet(currentSet.Id);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test the two cases of the trigger being called, so I've modified SetExport in such a way that I can replace the methods with a mock:

```
global with sharing virtual class SetExport {

    public static SetExport Instance = new SetExport();

    public virtual void exportMySetImpl(string setId) {
        // do API call to update our database
    }

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void exportMySet(string setId) {
        Instance.exportMySetImpl(setId);
    }

}
```

And the mock class:

```
class SetExportMock extends SetExport {

    public boolean IsCalled;
    public string ExportSetId;

    public override void exportMySetImpl(string setId) {
        this.IsCalled = true;
        this.ExportSetId = setId;
    }

}
```

**Problem**

In my test method I'm doing something like this:

```
// Setup
MySet__c mySet = new MySet__c(Name = 'Test');
insert mySet;

SetExportMock mockInstance = new SetExportMock();
SetExport.Instance = mockInstance;

Test.startTest();
// run code to execute trigger
// mySet.Name = 'test 123';
// update mySet;
Test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals(true, mockInstance.IsCalled);
```

The problem is that the `@future (callout=true)` annotation on `exportMySet` leads to it running *after* the mock instance has been assigned, so regardless of the code between `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` being executed, the test still passes because `IsCalled` was set to `true` by the trigger launched by `insert mySet;`.

**Question**

I've considered the following options:

1. Have a static Apex class flag to disable the triggers until my test setup is all done. - This seems a bit hacky.
2. Have separate methods for `insert` and `update` so that I can determine which type of action caused the trigger to run. - It works but it seems like adding excess code.
3. Use `Test.isRunningTest()` - this would presumably disable the trigger even when I want to test it.

Is there a better way to ensure that my setup code's triggers don't interfere with my tests?

Comment: I would start [on this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts) to see how to implement `HttpCalloutMock` to simulate API callouts.  There's a good code example about 3/4th down the page.  Another great trailhead with full examples [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform/mock-stub-objects)

Comment: @Brian Even if I did that, I think I'd be in the a similar situation but further down the line. The reason I wanted to mock the API call method is because I've already tested the API call method using a callout mock in isolation from the trigger itself. Now I'm just trying to test the triggers by themselves.